# Responsive Javascript Files?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I've built my mobile site using the jQuery Mobile UI but I now realize that I need some functionality to be different between it and my desktop site (datepicker dates should be longer on the desktop site, etc).

I've looked into Modernizr and matchMedia to help me load separate js files but I can't figure out a nice way for it to work responsively. Modernizr only works (unless I missed something in the doc) on the initial load and I'm having problems with matchMedia executing multiple times as it crosses the min/max-width threshold. It works sometimes but the trouble is in adding/removing the separate js files. On top of that (but not a huge issue - I don't think), Chrome fires off an error when loading scripts into the DOM from another script.

Would the best thing be to write one js file and then add a listener such as `$.mobile.media("screen and (min-width: XXXpx)")` to the body's width, changing my needed values?

I may be making this too hard for myself, or missing something obvious because I'm trying to keep HTTP requests and site size as small as possible, but I can't figure out a good solution for this.

Thank you!

*Lightning Round Bonus Question*: Is it good practice/proper to keep all of the jQuery Mobile styling (`data-role` `data-id` `data-theme`) after switching to the desktop site? It looks awfully .. awful for someone only viewing it on a larger screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the best approach would be to introduce a couple of flags in your javascript, like "isMobile", "isTablet" or "isDesktop", that would be set within a method attached to the "pageinit" event of your webapp. Later on, you could check that flags to act accordingly with the proper version in the specific parts of your code.

The way you can check that flags depends on your architecture. In the project I am working right now, I extract that information from a class attached by the back-end on the body of the page, but that's because we have that info. You could try to use a library like [Harvey](http://harvesthq.github.com/harvey/) to observe the media-queries that would be trigger, and set the flags accordingly. I don't think that your options ends here, but I am afraid I can't help you more!