# Conditionally load JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I need a JS statement that determine which JavaScript file to use.

I have one file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_computer.js"></script>
```

But when the screen width is less than 500px, I want load another file instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobile_version.js"></script>
```

I have tried everything and it is not working.

Comment: I cannot understand your question

Comment: He wants to use certain js code until the screen width is less than 500px.

Comment: i using this for css

<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 500px)' href="css/mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 2000px)' href="css/custom.css" />

I want to do the same for js

Comment: But this ist only css, what are you using for the "Javascript checking"?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811238/how-to-serve-up-different-javascript-files-by-browser-width

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run/load a separate javascript file selectively from inside javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208164/how-to-run-load-a-separate-javascript-file-selectively-from-inside-javascript)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682954/responsive-javascript-files.

Comment: http://cssmedia.pemor.pl/

Answer (score 75):

You'd have to create that markup yourself in JS. Something like this:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";

if (screen.width > 500)
{
    js.src = "js/jquery_computer.js";
}
else
{
    js.src = "js/mobile_version.js";
}

head.appendChild(js);
```

Comment: I like this approach.  And sometimes a script will fail to load so this concept of polling to see if your script made it can be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130921/is-the-callback-on-jquerys-getscript-unreliable-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong#answer-1131018

Comment: Mind that with screen.width on a desktop with a reduced browser window it will still give you the device width, not the actual space available. Depending on scenario you can use the built-in window.matchMedia (cf my answer) or keep screen.width

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069951/how-to-load-javascript-source-from-the-working-directory-of-the-current-source-f

Answer (score 38):

If you want the script loaded **asynchronously**, the other answers here do that.

If you want it loaded **synchronously** with page load, this is one of the very, very few remaining valid uses cases for `document.write`:

```
<script>
(function() { // Scoping function to avoid globals
    var src = /*you want the main version*/ ? "jquery_computer.js" : "mobile_version.js";
    document.write('<script src="js/' + src + '"><\/script>');
})();
</script>
```

(I've removed `type` because JavaScript is the default, specifying it isn't useful.)

Comment: Perfect for the `if (typeof Promise === 'function') {/*load a script */}` use case needed to work around microsoft's "Compatibility Solution."

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you can use [matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) and can load a script using [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$(function(){
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 500px)').matches) {
        $.getScript(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: I prefer a solution that doesn't depend on jQuery. I'm currently using YepNope (http://yepnopejs.com/) but I'd like to replace it with another solution considering the library's been deprecated by the author.

Answer (score 11):

Best would be to use built-in matchMedia API.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';

if(window.matchMedia("(min-width:500px)").matches) {
  script.src = 'js/jquery.slitslider.js';      
}else{
  script.src = 'js/mobile_version.js';      
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Drawback is that it is not supported in IE < 10

Answer (score 7):

You don't need jQuery for this, it suffices to create the `<script>` tag in the DOM dynamically:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.type = 'text/javascript';

if (<screen-width less than 500>)
    script.src = "js/mobile_version.js";
else
    script.src = "js/jquery_computer.js";

head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
    var width = $(document).width(),
        mobile = 500;

    if (width > mobile) {
        $('head').append('<script class="desktop" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_computer.js"></script>');
        $('head').find('.mobile').remove();
    } 
    else
    {
        $('head').append('<script class="mobile" type="text/javascript" src="js/mobile_version.js"></script>');
        $('head').find('.desktop').remove();
    }
});
```

just use if else to detect condition and use class on script element 
may be it help

Comment: Use `<script class="mobile" .... />` instead of `<script class="mobile" ....></script>` or you will get `unterminated string error`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the async `import()` if you like.

```
import(condition ? 'js/desktop_version.js' : 'js/mobile_version.js')
```

In a script tag with `<script type="module">` or inside a module loaded with `import()` from a regular `<script>` you can also use top-level await in the newest (experimental) browsers

```
<script type="module">
  await import(condition ? 'js/desktop_version.js' : 'js/mobile_version.js')      
</script>
```

But it won't work for every script.

- A common reason why is those UMD module bundler that adds a closure
   `(function(global){...}(this))` since `this` is undefined in modules.
- Third party scripts needs to have CORS enable to load
- Won't work in IE, but it's dead anyway
- See other [known differences](https://usefulangle.com/post/256/script-type-module-vs-script-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$.getScript` in jQuery

[see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)   for details

Comment: @user2190308 did you checked my answer

Comment: means what is your another problem

Comment: see here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208164/how-to-run-load-a-separate-javascript-file-selectively-from-inside-javascript