# How do I load a JavaScript resource conditionally based on the presence of a certain ID tag in a page's HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

## Situation

In a web application I'm helping maintain, a change is specified wherein a certain JavaScript script must load conditionally, depending on the presence or absence of a certain element ID on the page.

## Question

How best to achieve this result without external libraries and in a manner consistent with current accepted practice?

## Current approach idea

My thought at present is to do something like the following; I'd appreciate some guidance, including in re : whether this approach is advisable and / or better alternative methods.

```
// identify head of html 
const htmlHead = document.querySelector('head');

// identify desired change condition and assign 
const desiredIdPresent = document.querySelector('#foo');
      
// assign script creation      
const activeScript = document.createElement('script');
      activeScript.type = 'text/javascript';


// conditions determine which script loads
if (desiredIdPresent){
    activeScript.src =  '/foo.js';
} else {
    activeScript.src = '/bar.js';
};

// insert desired script into document head
htmlHead.appendChild(activeScript);
```

there are some somewhat similar situations and solutions in the following, which among others I've also used as reference:

[conditionally load javascript resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500728/conditionally-load-javascript-resource?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Conditionally load JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521343/conditionally-load-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the synchronous aspect of the loading of the page.
Your code seems to be trying to search for `#foo` before it is loaded.

The solution : put your script tag at the end of your body.
Example :

```
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>

    <script>
        // identify head of html 
const htmlHead = document.querySelector('head');

// identify desired change condition and assign 
const desiredIdPresent = document.querySelector('#foo');
console.log(desiredIdPresent);

// assign script creation      
const activeScript = document.createElement('script');
      activeScript.type = 'text/javascript';


// conditions determine which script loads
if (desiredIdPresent){
    activeScript.src =  '/foo.js';
} else {
    activeScript.src = '/bar.js';
};

// insert desired script into document head
htmlHead.appendChild(activeScript);
    </script>
    <!-- OR --> <script src="k.js"/>
</body>
```

I have no touched one centimeter of your JS.