# Execute javascript only in one environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 web app. I have a javascript plugin that I just want to execute in production environment (related with Google Analytics).

I have an ENVIRONMENT constant with different values according to environment, so my idea is to do something like:

```
<head>
<script ng-show="ENVIRONMENT == 'Production'">
  javascript code
</script>
</head>
```

or same with `ng-switch`.

However none of the seems to work, because I think they are rendered anyway, so finally the Google Analytics code is executed in every environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Conditionally load JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521343/conditionally-load-javascript-file)

It's easy to do without dependencies on any js library.

```
if (ENVIRONMENT == 'Production')
{    
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var js = document.createElement("script");    
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = "js/GoogleAnalitycs.js";
    head.appendChild(js);
}
```

Comment: Where do you ideally place this?

Comment: I think first js script you always include in your page is the best candidate. Be sure to assing ENVIRONMENT variable before using it.