# Executing 3rd party javascript within a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, conditional-statements

I have a 3rd party hosted script I wish to execute, but within a conditional loading script.

Loader:

```
<script>

  if (typeof({{Session alive}}) == "undefined") {
 <!-- 3rd party script I wish to execute -->

 }

var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+1800000);
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = "session=1; "+expires+"; path=/";
</script>
```

The 3rd party script I wish to execute is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.geolify.com/georedirect.php?id=7190'></script>
```

is there a way to have this 3rd party script execute only within the logic of the first container, while keeping the 3rd party script hosted on the external server still.

Any help ofcourse is much appreciated, thanks very much :)

Comment: Just create a script element and add it to the document; not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521343/conditionally-load-javascript-file) link will help.

Comment: lazy load it, lazy load

Comment: I should also add: the business logic of this was to load and execute an external js file, but only once per session on the original visit.

Comment: @Phoenix thank yout for sharing. Using that example would this final script work you think?

    `<script>

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    js.type = "text/javascript";

    if (typeof({{Session alive}}) == "undefined")
    {
        js.src = "https://www.geolify.com/georedirect.php?id=7190";
    }


    head.appendChild(js);

    var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime()+1800000);
      var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
      document.cookie = "session=1; "+expires+"; path=/";

    </script>`