# reponsive or device Conditionally load JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to try this code for my project its not working for me

```
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";

if (screen.width > 500)
{
    js.src = "js/jquery_computer.js";
}
else
{
    js.src = "js/mobile_version.js";
}

head.appendChild(js);
```

[Conditionally load JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521343/conditionally-load-javascript-file)

not working link

http://itracktraining.com/sam.html

New Changes, same above link for demo

this seems not working
i trying to call multiple jqueryfile and a function too :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var width = $(document).width()
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";

if (width > 800)
{
    js.src = "js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js";
    js.src = "js/jquery.fullPage.js";
    js.src = "js/examples.js";
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage'],
                sectionsColor: ['#C63D0F', '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C'],
                css3: true
            });
}
else
{
    js.src = "js/mobile_version.js";
}

head.appendChild(js);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the element `head` is not defined. You need to add the line:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

At the beginning of your script.

Also, it looks like you are missing the `screen` variable. You can swap `screen.width` with `window.innerWidth`.

Complete, working example at [jsfiddle.net/syLzb4yL](http://jsfiddle.net/syLzb4yL/2/).

---

Answer to edited question can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/AgVGniJT).

Comment: that script will show only if we inspect or just view source

Comment: What do you mean? You can see that the script indeed checks the width of the screen and debugs out `narrow` or `wide`. The scripts are not present (there are no `js/mobile_version.js` or `js/jquery_computer.js`) so of course that will not work.

Comment: i have updated the question kindly check same question

Comment: i trying to call multiple jqueryfile and a function too :)

Comment: No, because you use one instance of `js` and try to append three scripts to it. That will not work. You overwrite `src` every time. Why not just include these scripts with `<script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script><script src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>`

Comment: i don't know how to bring that jquery file, a function with mobile condition.. iam confused with try many examples

Comment: [Here is the entire output](http://pastebin.com/AgVGniJT) that should work. Mind that this is not tested, but it does answer the question as originally asked. If this does not work I suggest closing this question and asking a more detailed one where you express what you want in greater detail.