# How to conditionally load file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could somebody suggest me a way for loading css or javascript file conditionally i.e only if url is accessible?

for example on my page I have the following files:

```
<html>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://service.test/css/a.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://services.test/js/a.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

Is there any way to check if `https://service.test/css/a.css` is accessible then if yes load this resource (same for `https://services.test/js/a.js`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally load JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521343/conditionally-load-javascript-file)

Comment: Also, you need to make an `XHR` request to the resource you want to check for accessibility

Comment: Also see [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-pure-javascript).

Comment: Also see working example https://jsfiddle.net/pu3antasyah/v95Loyvu/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. but it will only work for the stylesheets that are in head section.

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://service.test/css/a.css"/>
<body>

</body>

<script>
// you will have to manuall define the pairs (keys are stylesheets and values are scripts you want to load)
const pairs = {
    "https://service.test/css/a.css": "https://services.test/js/a.js"
}

let styles = document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet'][type='text/css'][href]");

styles.forEach(s => {
  if(pairs[s.href]){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = pairs[s.href];    
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to check if a file is accessible before loading it.