# how I disable bootstrap scripts in IE ..Like browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the bootstrap file in chrome and edge but I don't want the bootstrap file in IE. Then only I will get output. Please help me with this question.
For alignments and adjustments, we use queries in CSS for browser compatibility, like same way I need to disable and enable some scripts in javascript also. Can anyone please help with the solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if user is using IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie)

Comment: [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056)

Comment: Tq for reply Kudlas..but I need to stop "<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>"  this script in IE..

Comment: Use conditional script from here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521343/conditionally-load-javascript-file
inside if use the previous post code.